# Select users who have records equal to y but not x

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which contains historical records for the votes given to entrants in a competition. A simplified example of the structure is:

```
id | entrantId | roundId | judgeId
```

Some example data:

```
401 | 32 | 3 | 4
402 | 32 | 3 | 5
403 | 35 | 3 | 4
404 | 32 | 4 | 4
405 | 36 | 3 | 4
406 | 36 | 3 | 10
```

I need to get all records of users who have a `judgeId = 4` and the `roundId = 3` but where the same 'entrantId' doesn't have a record of any kind where `roundId = 4`

So using the data above, I would be looking to retrieve records `403` and `405` since these entrants(35 & 36) have records for judge 4 in round 3 but have no records in round 4 (eg roundId = 4).

I'm assuming I'd need to have a SELECT statement that uses an 'IN' based clause, but I don't know enough about this to be able to build a suitable query.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab t1
WHERE judgeId = 4 
  AND roundId = 3
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tab t2
                  WHERE t1.entrantId = t2.entrantId
                    AND t2.roundId = 4);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/422631)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦═══════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ id  ║ entrantId ║ roundId ║ judgeId ║
╠═════╬═══════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ 403 ║        35 ║       3 ║       4 ║
║ 405 ║        36 ║       3 ║       4 ║
╚═════╩═══════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

---

Alternatively using windowed functions:

```
WITH cte AS(
SELECT *,
  c = COUNT(CASE WHEN roundId = 4 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY entrantId)
FROM #tab
)
SELECT id,entrantId,roundId,judgeId
FROM cte
WHERE c = 0
  AND judgeId = 4 
  AND roundId = 3;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/422658)**</kbd>

Comment: Are there any significant advantages of one method over the other (eg speed, best practice) ?

Comment: @PhillHealey First will work with most RDBMS, second won't for example MySQL does not implement `ROW_NUMBER`. For your case I would use first solution

Answer (score 0):

You might use except but you won't get the ID.

```
select entrantId 
  from table 
 where roundId = 3 and judgeId = 4 
except 
select entrantId 
  from table 
 where roundId = 4;
```

Answer (score -2):

Simply and most readable and direct use NOT IN subquery as follows

```
SELECT * FROM Votes WHERE judgeId = 4 AND roundId = 3
AND entrantId NOT IN (SELECT entrantId FROM Votes WHERE roundId = 4)
```

Comment: Please don't promote the use of "not in". It commonly adds bugs to systems based on the three valued logic of TSQL and developers who aren't aware, http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/05/18/60210.aspx . Always use "exists" instead of "in" unless the list is hardcoded.

Comment: @shriop Good tip. Does that mean we need to use 'NOT EXISTS' ??

Comment: @shriop do you know that "SET ANSI_NULLS ON" fixes the NULLs issues?

Comment: @AtheerMostafa , yes, I know what "SET ANSI_NULLS ON" does. I do not agree with your definition of "fixes". It's more of the same non-obvious land mines that I'm asking people to stop leaving laying around for the juniors to blow their toes off with. Why would you not just want to use the correct statement syntax? There's no benefit to using "not in" when working in TSQL, and far too many pitfalls.